script in systemd service behaves different than running manually
I have a systemd service which runs a loop to check if a smb share is available and mounts it once it is. This works fine for one share, but not fine for another.
After waiting for the share to be accessible (using nc) the systemd service runs this command as root
mount -t cifs //192.168.122.49/pool/ /mnt/pool -o credentials=/etc/nixos/credentials,uid=1000,gid=100,vers=3.1.1,rw

and fails with failed: Permission denied. Systemd tells me status=255/EXCEPTION
Restarting the systemd service always results in this error. If I run this command myself with sudo mount ... everything works. I have another service that works exactly like this and this one works just fine without manually running the command.
How could such a difference occur?
Is it because the systemd service cannot read the credentials file? Its owned by root and has permissions -rw-------

Well I changed the script to systemctl restart mnt-pool.mount and this works. It really does seem like the script inside the systemd service could not access the credentials file and then failed to login. Weird
